# JAXB - Map schema to different fields of same object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, schema, marshalling

I'm trying to use JAXB in my project and I found an issue that with Jibx was easy to handle (we stopped using it with jboss 7) but with JAXB we are having difficulties to solve.

So I have a class A as follows:

```
    public class A
    {
        @XmlElement(name ="xpto")
        public B fieldXPTO;

        @XmlElement(name ="foo")
        public B fieldFOO;
    }
```

And my class B :

```
    public class B
    {
        public String name;
        public String address;
    }
```

Now building our schema for class A we wanted to specify different names for the class B fields for each class A field. Something that when marshalling an A object would turn out like

```
    <A>
        <xpto>
          <name_xpto>Peter</name_xpto>
          <address_xpto>Moon Street</address_xpto>
        </xpto>
        <foo>
          <name_foo>Ryan</name_foo>
          <address_foo>Mars Street</address_foo>
        </foo>        
    </A>
```

Is it possible to do this just by working with the schema ?

Thank you all,

Pedro

Comment: How do you express it using XML Schema? Write this, compile with xjc, and that will be the answer.

Comment: Hi @Iaune , thanks for your reply. What if I want to achieve this just by using annotations ? I was thinking if there is a way to add prefixes or suffixes to all fields of an object. I've been reading documentation but still nothing helpful about this particular issue.

Comment: There is no convenient way. You could design one Java class for each of the B variants, but they would be different Java classes, and then you'd have to write adapters mapping the B variants to the "real" B. This is a very cumbersome way, and I really wonder what the benefit of this non-XML-ish procedure could be.